# Pulling GitHub Actions images via Docker Hub whilst authenticated

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action which uses various services to run, for example:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.5
```

We're moving to running these jobs on self-hosted runners, but we keep hitting Docker Hub rate limits:

```
Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

The thing that is broken though is that I have a Docker Hub account and we have been adding a step from [the suggested action](https://github.com/docker/login-action) to try and remedy this, but because the images are being pulled before that code gets to execute it doesn't seem to be logging in.

Is there a way of using the services, whilst pulling their images from Docker Hub authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Supply [credentials for pulling the service image](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idcredentials) in the workflow YAML:

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.5
    credentials:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```